# How to speed up VBA code for hiding rows?

Tags: excel, vba

With VBA I have created a toggle button that hides and unhides rows, however it's really slow. To hide 200 rows it takes roughly 2 minutes. Is there a way I can speed this code up? My goal would be under 10 seconds if that's at all possible.

Here's my code:

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub ToggleButton1_Click()

Dim bHide As Boolean
Dim rCell As Range
bHide = ToggleButton1.Value

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.EnableEvents = False

For Each rCell In Range("AC10:AC800")
If rCell.Value = 1 Then
If Not rCell Is Nothing Then
Rows(rCell.Row).Hidden = bHide
End If
End If
Next 

Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Application.EnableEvents = True 

End Sub
```

Thanks for any help!

Comment: What is `If Not rCell Is Nothing Then` supposed to accomplish?

Comment: Does `Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual` help speed it up for you?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In VBA, reading and writing to worksheets is the biggest time killer. So, you want to minimize how often you interact with worksheets.

Luckily, you can read multiple values or hide multiple rows in a single command, instead of having a command for every single value or row.

Something like this:

```
Private Sub ToggleButton1_Click()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim rangeToCheck As Range
    Dim rangeToHide As Range
    Dim sheetData() As Variant
    Dim curRow As Long

    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1") 'Change to your worksheet name
    Set rangeToCheck = ws.Range("AC10:AC800")

    sheetData = rangeToCheck.Value  'Read all data from the range into an array at once

    For curRow = LBound(sheetData) To UBound(sheetData)
        If sheetData(curRow, 1) = 1 Then 'Check contents of each row, and add to range to hide if the check is true
            If rangeToHide Is Nothing Then
                Set rangeToHide = rangeToCheck.Rows(curRow).EntireRow
            Else
                Set rangeToHide = Union(rangeToHide, rangeToCheck.Rows(curRow).EntireRow)
            End If
        End If
    Next curRow

    'If at least one row was found, hide all rows at once
    If Not rangeToHide Is Nothing Then rangeToHide.EntireRow.Hidden = ToggleButton1.Value
End Sub
```

Comment: Wow this worked great at hiding the rows thanks so much, but the toggle button no longer seems to work at unhiding the rows?

Comment: Oh, sure, I didn't see that part of the question. Just change the line `rangeToHide.EntireRow.Hidden = True` to `rangeToHide.EntireRow.Hidden = ToggleButton1.Value`

Answer (score 0):

Another way is just to gather address. In the accepted answer you constantly need to check `If rangeToHide Is Nothing`. In this method, however, you don't have to do it.

```vb
Sub HideUnhide()
    Dim addr, cell
    For Each cell In [AC10:AC800]
        If cell = 1 Then addr = addr & cell.Address(0, 0) & ","
    Next
    If Len(addr) > 0 Then
        addr = Left$(addr, Len(addr) - 1) '//Get rid of last comma
        Range(addr).EntireRow.Hidden = ToggleButto1.Value
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: This isn't really a different approach, it's just using a string to collect the ranges, instead of a range object. Also, you're taking out one of the two major speed gains, which is reading in all values to an array, instead of reading the value of each cell individually. In terms of speed, checking whether an object is nothing is, well, nothing.

Comment: Rather than checking `cell = 1` 800 times (ie, 800 read operations on the worksheet), it's much faster to copy all values into an array (1 read operation), then check `array(x) = 1` 800 times.

Comment: @JohnyL: Did you test the posted code? I am afraid that such a range composed from discontinued cells cannot be created. Am I wrong or do I miss something?

Comment: @FaneDuru Yes, I tested it.

Comment: I received on this line `Range(addr).EntireRow.Hidden = True` the error "**Run-time error '1004': Method 'Range' of object '_Global' failed**"

Comment: @FaneDuru Well, I don't see what you're doing, thus can't say why you get this error.

Comment: @JohnyL: I have just copied the code, filled AC column with random 1 positions, in the range 10 - 800, replaced ToggleButto1.Value with True and run the code.

Comment: @JohnyL: I checked your answer deeper. You probably checked the code for a limited number of occurrences. It works until the string length is less or equal to 256 characters. Over this amount, Excel returns the mentioned above error.

Answer (score 0):

I think that using AutoFilter is the fastest method, needing a shorter piece of code.

```
Private Sub rngFilterHide()
  Dim sh As Worksheet, sR As Range, rngHhide As Range

    Set sh = ActiveSheet 'Use here your sheet name
    Set sR = sh.Range("AC10:AC800")
    sR.AutoFilter field:=1, Criteria1:="=1", VisibleDropDown:=False
      Set rngHhide = sR.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
      sh.AutoFilterMode = False
      rngHhide.EntireRow.Hidden = ToggleButto1.Value
      If sh.Range("AC10") <> 1 Then sh.Rows("10:10").Hidden = Not ToggleButto1.Value
End Sub
```